# Laravel default .htaccess file will not work

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I finally got everything installed for Laravel, but I am getting an error 500 on my home page!

It looks to be my .htaccess file. If I remove it the page works.  If I put it back, another error 500.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I change that second to last line to "RewriteRule ^index.php [L]" (no space before index.php) then the error 500 goes away but the rewrite rule will not work.

My host is 1and1.com.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Changed this line:

```
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

to this:

```
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Now it works.  Not only do I not get the 500 error, but the URLs appear to work as intended.

Comment: Could anyone explain why this happens and why this fix works?

Comment: This is one of those cases where I wish I could upvote several times. Thanks for your help as 1and1 support is less than worthless.

Comment: that doesn't work if you have a folder within a folder. This redirects to e.g. `localhost/index.php`

Comment: Still the fix on Ionos in 2022

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me the 500 internal error is coming because you have not set the virtual host in the apache httpd.conf file.

Put this line in the httpd.conf file

For windows

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourlaravel.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/laravel/public"
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/laravel/public">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
     <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For Linux

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourlaravel.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/laravel/public">
 </Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot "/var/www"
   <Directory "/var/www">
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And to run it in your local machine

For window open the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts put this line.

```
 yourserverip   yourlaravel.com
```

For linux open the \etc\hosts put this line.

```
 yourserverip   yourlaravel.com
```

Your can refer to this link for further info:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/building-web-applications-from-scratch-with-laravel/

I hope this can be some help.

Comment: I am on a shared hosting environment so I cannot change my https.conf file.

Answer (score 2):

It work for me on the most of the project where default one won't work

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

create .htaccess file in your root folder then page the code bellow in the file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and the error suddenly happened overnight.

I have searched all over google and Stackoverflow, but i couldn't find any solutions to fix this problem, and i kept getting a 500 Internal Server error.

I was on a shared hosting, and even renaming the .htaccess file didn't work.

At the buttom of .htaccess i put

```
php_flag opcache.enable 0
```

right before the ending `</IfModule>` . This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

I also experienced this issue and solved it by commenting option line in .htaccess file..

Using apache 2.4.x

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        #Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

It may conflicting with the site configuration.
Because it cannot have multiple condition with different operator.

I cannot find the link yet.
But I've read it somewhere before.

**EDIT**: Found the [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options).

> Note
>
> Mixing Options with a + or - with those without is not valid syntax and will be rejected during server startup by the syntax check with an abort.

Just make sure your .htaccess and apache configuration is not conflicting each other.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13248156)

Comment: Oh sorry if my answer does not really answer OP's question. What I mean is that I tried commenting the option line. And then the error solved.