# Laravel isn´t working on Shared Server based on Linux

Tags: .htaccess, configuration, laravel

does anybody know how to setup Laravel that it´ll work on a shared Server based on Linux?
I´ve tried default and alternative .htaccess files:

- when I type a url which doesn´t exists and isn´t defined in routes.php I get this:
  .

**Internal Server Error**

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error. More information about this error may be available in the server error log. Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

- when I type a url to a folder which exists but isn´t defined in routes.php I get a Redirect Loop
- when I type a url to a file which exists but isn´t defined in routes.php I get same Error like first one

here the .htaccess files I´ve tried with (both behave same)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228936/laravel-default-htaccess-file-will-not-work?rq=1

Comment: adding a Slash to the last line fixed the Internal Server Errors but not the redirect Loop - and I too can´t access the virtual host config because my Provider doesn´t offer that Service

Comment: Try adding `RewriteBase /` just after `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: @RMcLeod I´ve done that like so `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /` still having redirect Loop when pathing to folder (e.g. mydomain/images)