# Laravel 5 shared hosting deployment issues

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to deploy laravel 5.2  on shared hosting.

I installed the laravel core app folder a level above the public_html folder (/../public_html or /home/username ).

I extracted the files in the laravel core public folder (public) and pointed the  index.php file to the laravel core app folder a root above (/../laravel-app/bootstrap/autoload.php and /../laravel-app/bootstrap/app.php).

The website homepage is working but pages links are returning a 404 and it isnt pulling in any css or js.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Points to note: 
I am on php ver 5.6
I changed the file permission in laravel-app/storage to a 777
I deleted the .htaccess fil in the public_html folder
Server is apache

Comment: do you use `asset()` in your code to link resources? (css, js, img...)

Comment: Why have you deleted .htaccess? This file is important for routing. When you dont have correct .htaccess, then links are not sending to Laravel index.php so it is trying to acces to folders/files, which dont exist (so you get 404)

Comment: OK. So how do I get a new .htaccess file?

Comment: No. I didn't use assets() to link to resources.  However I not sure. How do I check?

Answer (score 2):

Buddy just follow this tutorial, I tried it and it's working just fine!

https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.5lywcjmnn

Btw, you don't even need the last part after this sentence

> If you don’t have composer installed already on your server, you can easily grab it to the project directory then.

In my case I did the following:
placing laravel project outside of public_html as `lara` folder

then I had this htaccess in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and inside public_html I had .htacess with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^awesome
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ awesome/$1 [L]
```

Where `awesome` is the directory that contains htacess (listed down) and index.php, favicon and robots.txt:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

final change is in index.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

/* die(__DIR__);  /home/{YOURHOST}/public_html/awesome */
require __DIR__.'/../../lara/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../lara/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: How do I run the compser command? I dont have access to the server via ssh. Another thing. I did everything listed in the tutorial (as far as I could understand and still getting the error).  However, I dont have a  .htaccess file (I deleted it erroneously).

Comment: Upload your local version of `.htaccess`, and regarding the composer command you don't have to, the convention saying is: composer update should run on local only in this case only composer.lock is what going to be changed, in your case you have to upload the vendor folder too, don't ignore it :)

Comment: Thats the problem. I mistakenly deleted it (the .htaccess file). What do I do?

Comment: I'm running at this very moment nginx, so I can't test it for you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228936/laravel-default-htaccess-file-will-not-work

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think it's a .htaccess file problrmproblem too but I have no way to verify. I  will  have to find a way to get it

Comment: Where did you put the files in from the laravel app in the `public` directory?

Comment: inside public there were only the files I listed in my answer, which they are:
.htacess,index.php,robots.txt favicon and one more I didn't list, which is web.config.. that's it, all of my project files are **outside** of public_html, and **inside** `lara` folder

Comment: I am still having issues. I think the problem is a  .htaccess file problem. I only have one .htaccess file located in the public_html folder. I also put my index.php file in the public_html folder. Where else should I put the .htaccess and what should be in it? I installed the laravel app in public_html/app and moved the indrx.php file and the .htaccess files to public_html/ folder. Thank you

Comment: i do go through your steps but css, js folder path issue, page are breaking. Thanks.

Comment: @Y.JoyCh.Singha Dude, this is a very old answer (2016) I will try to update it soon :)