# How can I update my composer in the godaddy shared hosting developed with the laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, installation, composer-php

I want to publish my site.But i can not do it.So need help to update composer in godaddy hosting.

Comment: do you have ssh access?

Comment: No i don't know details about ssh.

Comment: do you have composer installed on the server?

Comment: No i could not do this also.I confuse about the whole process starting from access ssh to install composer by puTTy and bitvice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Composer installed and so laravel too. All you need is to deploy your application in local machine and zip it and then upload the particular Domain/Sub Domain folder.

> Need to do some configuration changes in the following files

- you have to move all public folder files in the main application folder
- you need to edit index.php of the following
- from `require _DIR_./../bootstrap/autoload.php;` to `require _DIR_./bootstrap/autoload.php;`
- from `$app = require_once_DIR_.'/../bootstrap/app/php';` to $app = require_once_DIR_.'/bootstrap/app/php';

Since you moved the UI file structure so you need to do changes in "master.blade.php" also. mostly CSS error will through so locate you css pointer and change this from `href="{{ asset(elixir('css/app.css')) }}"` to `href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}"`

change .env files also.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply upload the `composer.lock` with your files. don't gitignore it.

now if you want to upload your Laravel app into a shared hosting follow these steps:

[I wrote it in another answer so I won't copy and paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033088/2131039)